# Did Microsoft change the way to pass string as parameter in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have this simple question. Previously, when I wanted to call a controller method with only one parameter, I could do it simply calling `/ControllerName/Method/Parameter`, whatever type this parameter was. Now, I did the same thing with an integer value without problems, but with a string it didn't work. Am I going nuts or Microsoft actually changed this?

Comment: Could you provide some code? Mainly your route setup and controller action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default route that you'll find in Global.aspx.cs is still the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

So your "parameter" is the `{id}` in the example above, presumably a number as IDs tend to be. Get to know your routes, they're fun! Linkage: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs

Answer (score 0):

I'm imagining your actions that work for `int`s look something like this:

`public ActionResult Index(int id)`

If you want to accept a string parameter instead of an integer and have it be part of the (default) route, it also would need to be named `id` in the method signature, like so:

`public ActionResult Index(string id)`

If you had an action with a signature like this:

`public ActionResult Post(string slug)`

Then with the default route slug would only have a value if you had a querystring (`get`) or form (`post`) value with the key `slug`.  A route that would match the above action and have the `slug` parameter be populated (assuming it was a method of the `BlogController` controller) would be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "BlogPost",                                             
    "post/{slug}",                           
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "Post", slug = "" }  
);
```